# How to maintain a decoupled git component?

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

Let's say I have some pet-projects on Laravel (or any other PHP project with Composer).

They have some similar functionality and I want to extract in into a composer package hosted on GitHub.

**What are my actions?**

I see this approach:

1. Create a new project (e.g. in PhpStorm). Write an extension with tests (migrate from one of the projects).
2. Create a GitHub repository, push the code there.
3. Add it to packagist.
4. Composer require the package on all projects and install it properly.

This is ok. But what if I need to add some new feature or fix a bug? **How do I do it properly?**

It's convenient to try it directly on some of the projects, which has the extension installed, but it's strange to edit "vendor" directory, and even if the files are edited, how to push them back to the repository?

It's also awkward to edit the code in the separate PHPStorm project for the repository "blindly" and push it each time, the composer update from the project to see how it works.

**Any other convenient flow? Thanks.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to install your library to test it, you're doing something wrong. :) You are absolutely right that that is not a nice way to work. Here's a better way: Write tests—lots of tests—that you can run on your library to make sure it works. Since you're using PHP, use [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/) for this part.

If you do find a bug while using the library in one of your other projects, write a test that exercises that bug. Then you can code —> test —> repeat in your library until the tests pass again.